# How to do indexOf with exact match?

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I have multiple complex strings, e.g. `<a href=\"/Notice/Details` or `Number: <strong>` for which I need to know the starting index in a string they are searched in. Dart of Flutter has an `indexOf` method for a String, but it requires a regex pattern. How can I do an indexOf search without regex pattern but with plain string match?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Regex for `indexOf` method. You can test this very simple code on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/):

```dart
void main() {
  String test = 'TESTTEXT<a href=\"/Notice/DetailsMORETESTTEXT';
  print(test.indexOf('<a href=\"/Notice/Details'));
}
```

And the result will be an `8` printed on the console. (8 is the start index of '<a href=\"/Notice/Details')